# FactoryGirl methods not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm testing a Rails application using RSpec and Capybara. I decided to use FactoryGirl too. I added this line to my Gemfile and ran `bundle install`:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
```

According to the instructions on the FactoryGirl GitHub page I also added this line to `spec/support/factory_girl.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

I have added some factories in `spec/factories.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :trip_plan do
    title "A New Plan"
    day 15
  end
end
```

My `rails_helper.rb` (without tons of comments):

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

But now when I try to run FactoryGirl methods in my model specs (in `spec/models/trip_plan_spec.rb`) like:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TripPlan, type: :model do
  describe 'the day validation process' do
    it 'validates that day in between 1 and 365' do
      t1 = create(:trip_plan)
      # Some more validations here...
    end
  end
end
```

I get an error saying `undefined method 'create'`. How will I solve this?

Comment: Can you post some more code? Where exactly do you call `create` method?

Comment: I have added the spec where I'm trying to run the FactoryGirl methods.

Comment: I also get the error when running FactoryGirl methods in the Rails console.

Comment: @AbraarArique could you post your `rails_helper.rb`?

Comment: Did you run this `FactoryGirl.create(:trip_plan)`  in a console?

Comment: @caspg Yes, when I run the methods prefixed with `FactoryGirl` it works. But with the modification to `spec/support/factory_girl.rb` it should work without `FactoryGirl` prefixed (according to https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed this line in your `rails_helper.rb` configuration:

`Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }`

Which is responsible for reading your `support` files like `factory_girl.rb`.

Comment: No problem, happy testing. :)